# JsonPath : filter by value in array

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I'm trying to filter by value an array in my Json with Jsonpath. I want to get the long_name of the country in the JSON below. In order to do that, I filter the adress_components by types[0] == "country" but it doesn't seem to work.

**The JsonPath I tried :**

```
$.results[0].address_components[?(@['types'][0]=="country")].long_name
```

The result I want is : "Canada".

**The JSON :**

```
{
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "5510-5520",
                   "short_name" : "5510-5520",
                   "types" : [ "street_number" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Yonge Street",
                   "short_name" : "Yonge St",
                   "types" : [ "route" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Willowdale",
                   "short_name" : "Willowdale",
                   "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "North York",
                   "short_name" : "North York",
                   "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Toronto",
                   "short_name" : "Toronto",
                   "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Toronto Division",
                   "short_name" : "Toronto Division",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Ontario",
                   "short_name" : "ON",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Canada",
                   "short_name" : "CA",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "M2N 5S3",
                   "short_name" : "M2N 5S3",
                   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                }
             ]
            }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you doing this in Java?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following JSONPath will work:

```
$..address_components[?(@.types[0] == 'country')].long_name
```

Breaking it down:

- `$..address_components`: focus on the `address_components` array
- `[?(@.types[0] == 'country')]`: find the `address_components` sub document having a type attribute named "type" containing an array of which the first value is "country"
- `.long_name`: return the `long_name` attribute of this sub document.

Verified using the [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) and in Java:

```
JSONArray country = JsonPath.parse(json)
    .read("$..address_components[?(@.types[0] == 'country')].long_name");

// prints Canada
System.out.println(country.get(0));
```

Answer (score 6):

The working solution offered by glytching won't anymore if *country* is not the first one of the types array.

You should rather use:

```
$..address_components[?(@.types.indexOf('country') != -1)]
```

It will filter by **array contains country**, rather than **array starts with country**