# Jsonpath: get the value of an element based on its sibling, when the sibiling element is an array containing a specific value

Tags: json, jsonpath, jayway

With the following json:

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "ids": [
        {
          "id": "A"
        },
        {
          "id": "B"
        }
      ],
      "value": "one"
    },
    {
      "ids": [
        {
          "id": "C"
        },
        {
          "id": "D"
        }
      ],
      "value": "two"
    }
  ]
}
```

What would be the jsonpath to return the value **one** when asking for the id **A**?

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/47576707 I can retrieve the **ids** element containing **A**:

`$.elements.*.ids[?(@.id=='A')]` or `$..ids[?(@.id=='A')]`

with result:

```
[
   {
      "id" : "A"
   }
]
```

but I would like to access the value of its sibling (`"value": "one"`).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `in` [filter operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators).

```
$.elements[?('A' in @.ids.*.id)].value
```

Answer (score 1):

jsonpath:

`$.elements[?(@.ids.*.id contains 'A')].value`

result:

```
[
   "one"
]
```